# nested ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using [ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/) to put an array structure into a table the following way :

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" ng-controller="VenueListCtrl">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="entry in venues">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in entry">
        <td data-title="key">
          {{val}}
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Consider venues to be :

```
[{"id":"C001","name":"Bobo"},{"id":"C002","name":"Shobo"},{"id":"C003","name":"Soho"}]
```

The first `ng-repeat` works okay as I can see the 3 rows in the table. The second `ng-repeat` doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [*Table Row Element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) (`<tr>`) can not accept a `<div>` as a child. You must directly use the second `ngRepeat` on the *Table Cell Element* (`<td>`):

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" ng-controller="VenueListCtrl">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="entry in venues">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in entry" data-title="key">
        {{val}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Good catch, thanks ! Unfortunately, doing it like this messes up the table headers for some reason (`key` is not recognised in `data-title` attribute, ng-table related probably. I guess that is why he specifically [gives an example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/20) with dynamic columns

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` element can't be a direct child of `<tr>`. You need to simply put your inner ngRepeat on `td`element:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" ng-controller="VenueListCtrl">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="entry in venues">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in entry" data-title="key">
        {{val}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Waoh! Second for second :P!